# can't change datediff unit

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, heidisql

`czn, cza` both are datetime data type (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
`datediff(czn, cza)` works but it gives me a day difference,
when I try
`datediff('second',czn,cza)` it's not working,
I tried 's', 'minute','h' etc.
And also tried to change data format into `"%Y-%m-%d-%h-%i-%s"`

*Error: SQL (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'*

Comment: HediSQL is a GUI interface, not a database.  You should tag your question with the database you are actually using.  Based on the error message, I have done this for you, adding the "sql-server" tag.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are referring to is a SQL Server error.  HeidiSQL is just a GUI interface to the underlying database.

You cannot pass this in as a parameter, because it is a SQL keyword.  The best you can do in a regular SQL statement is a `case` expression, such as:

```
(case @parameter
     when 'second' then datadiff(second, czn, cza)
     when 'minute' then datadiff(minute, czn, cza)
     when 'hour' then datadiff(hour, czn, cza)
     when 'day' then datadiff(day, czn, cza)
 end)
```